# ASP.NET 4x and ASP.net Core on the same machine

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

My question is very simple, but I will ask it at the risk of sounding like an idiot.

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server called "machine" running several production web applications (asp WebForm) on an IIS ASP.net 4.X server.

Now, I would like to develop MVC web applications (targeting .NET Core platform) using the MVC with the tag helpers available only with ASP CORE.

Is it possible to install ASP Core on the  server "machine" while maintaining the existing applications and then deploy new ASP Core web application (with visual studio 2019) ? The objective is to run production application WebForm (.Net Framework) and MVC application (ASP Core) on the same machine.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: You may have to do additional work - please see [Install .NET Core on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=netcore31#dependencies) for some dependencies. I assume you know that on January 14, 2020, support for Windows Server 2008 and 2008 R2 ended.

Answer (score -1):

Yes Just download supported installer from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=netcore31).
Now you can easily host asp.net 4.X & .net core application in same IIS without any issue.